# Laravel 8 - How to set a different relation name for scoping in Nested Resource Route

Tags: php, laravel, routes

### Routes:

I have a nested resource route. I use this to declare it:

```php
Route::resource('orders.comments', \App\Http\Controllers\Backend\OrderCommentController::class)
    ->parameters([
        'comments' => 'orderComment:id'
    ])
    ->except(['show']);
```

### Models & Relations:

I have two models, `Order` and `OrderComment`.

`Order` model:

```php
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderComment::class);
}
```

`OrderComment` model:

```php
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
}
```

### OrderComment Controller edit method signature

```php
public function edit(Order $order, OrderComment $orderComment)
```

### The actual problem

Whenever I want to edit an order comment, by visiting `/orders/1/comments/1/edit`, I get the error:

```
Call to undefined method App\Models\Order::orderComments()
```

I assume this is based on the parameter I set in the resource. But I need the parameter to be `orderComment` and not `comment`, due to the `$orderComment` argument in `OrderCommentController@edit`. This is mainly due to the name convention.

### Possible, ruled out solutions i tried/considered:

Renaming the `OrderComment` model to `Comment`. This is not possible because there are other Comment models, with different columns, so it cannot be polymorphic too.

Renaming the `comments` relation to `orderComments`. This is *a* solution, but not a preferred one. This is because `$order->comments` looks more elegant than `$order->orderComments`, etc

### Conclusion/question

So is it possible to 'tell' Laravel it should look for a relation called `comments` instead of `orderComments`?

Comment: What happens if you pass `public function edit(Order $order, OrderComment $comment)`?

Comment: @Tpojka for that I have to also edit the route parameter from orderComment to comment, so I will test that.

And it works. I'll have to accept that I have to use `$comment` as variable name instead of `$orderComment`.

Comment: This also thought me that Laravel guesses the relation's name based on OrderCommentController@edit arguments name (`OrderComment $comment`) instead of route parameter name.

Comment: You can check route bindings in docs, could be found lot of useful things there. Also, I can warmly suggest to check [laravel best practices](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices) where can be found various naming conventions and other appropriate standards for framework.